# How to prove following equality using given hint?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_{n}\}$ be a convergent sequence such that $\{x_{n}\ge 0\}$  and ${k}\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{x_{n}^\frac{1}{k}}=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}{x_{n}}\right)^\frac{1}{k}.$$Hint: Find an expression $q$ such that $\frac{x_{n}^\frac{1}{k}-x^\frac{1}{k}}{x_{n}-x}=\frac{1}{q}.$

I know how to use expression like $q$ for $k=2$. How to solve for any $k$?

Comment: Note that the result follows since the function $f(x)=x^{1/k}$, where $x\in[0,+\infty[$, is continuous.

Comment: Hint2: $$\frac{a-b}{a^k-b^k}=\frac1{a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}b+a^{k-3}b^2+\dots+b^{k-1}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand the actual role of $q$ in your question by i have a solutions for this. Assuming that $x_n$ converges to $x > 0$ we can make a usefull substitusion. Let $y_n = \cfrac{x_n}{x}$. Clearly $y_n > 0$ since $x_n$ and $x$ are, and also
$y_n \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow \infty} 1$. In this set up we just need to prove that $\sqrt[k]{y_n} \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow \infty} 1$.
We can use that for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $$t^k-1 = (t-1)(t^{k-1} + t^{k-2} + \cdots+t+1)$$
hence
$t-1 = \cfrac{t^k-1}{t^{k-1} + \cdots+1}$.

We can use this fact with $t = \sqrt[k]{y_n}$:

$$\left| \sqrt[k]y_n - 1 \right| = \left| \cfrac{y_n-1}{y_n^\frac{k-1}{k} + \cdots + y_n^\frac{1}{k} + 1} \right| =  \cfrac{|y_n-1|}{y_n^\frac{k-1}{k} + \cdots + y_n^\frac{1}{k} + 1}$$
Where in the last equality we use that $y_n > 0$. Now if we maximise the denomitar we've done. To do so, we know that $y_n \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow \infty} 1$ then there must exist $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y_n > \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n > N$.
Finally
$$\left| \sqrt[k]y_n - 1 \right| =  \cfrac{|y_n-1|}{y_n^\frac{k-1}{k} + \cdots + y_n^\frac{1}{k} + 1} \leq \cfrac{|y_n-1|}{k/2} \leq \cfrac{2}{k} \, |y_n-1|$$
with should prove the statement.

Comment: Please, do not answer very low-quality questions!